# AWS Cognito: Restrict users to a one login at a time

Tags: amazon-cognito

Is there any way to restrict users to a single [simultaneous] session?

I'd like to be able to check if the current user already has a session. If they do, then they can opt to sign that session out, before continuing.

To be clear, at the moment it is **possible to login the same user from multiple browser tabs**, (from the same cognito application)

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
  cognitoUser: this.cognitoUser,
  onSuccess: (result) => {
    this.userSession = result
    console.log('successfully logged in', result)
    // But are they already logged in somewhere else?
  },
  onFailure: (error) => {
    console.log('Login failed for some reason...')
    callback(error)
  }
}
```

I understand that Cognito is built with mobiles/apps in mind so this might not be possible without using a login lambda hook... ? Even then I'm not sure if it's possible without maintaining a table of logged in users...?!

Answer (score 2):

You can signs the current user out globally from all the devices by invalidating all issued tokens

`cognitoUser.globalSignOut();`

or signs the current user out from the application in existing session in the browser.

`if (cognitoUser != null) {
   cognitoUser.signOut();
 }`

You can onvoke either of the above just before user sigins in back again using the login screen.

Comment: I think that might work... it won't actually tell us IF the user is signed in somewhere else though... like another device, or a private tab, etc. But it would force only a single session I think.. we'll try it out.

Comment: @comfytoday did you try this? what was your conclusion

Comment: this also signs all other users out. I am currently setting credentials using aws.config.credentials. Should I creating credentials separately for each user so signout doesnt sign everyone out?

Comment: @user2763557 Not sure what you mean by signing all other users out?? That shouldn't be possible. globalSignOut() works for the currently signed in user. See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#sign-out That's amplify, but same scenario. It works, but doesn't necessarily solve the issue I had when I created this question.

Comment: @comfytoday looks like i had to get user first using the accesstoken thne use aws.config credentials to get the temp credentials or to signout that particular user. Otherwise it signing out everyone

Comment: @user2763557 That's pretty interesting... from what you described, your client side code is able to signout all users? Or are am I misunderstanding the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I used the admin API - "AdminUserGlobalSignOut" for invalidating all the session tokens provided to the user before I send the login request from my lambda to Cognito.

You can refer to this link for official docs from aws.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUserGlobalSignOut.html

> Pro Tip - AdminUserGlobalSignOut endpoint kills the refresh token
> validity not the Id Token validity - so if the creds are shared at
> 12pm and the user signs in using another device in 5 mins or so - the
> first device ID token login will still work on the first device until
> its not expired - by default ID Token is valid for 1 hour.